# VB.net Button Styles And Templates (Windows Store)

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

For example, when I hover a button with a pointer, it changes color. Or when it is pressed, it gets some other color. How can I edit what color it gets in those situations? I found this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709909.aspx , but I don't understand how to edit Visual States of a button.

Comment: See if this answer works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087801/create-simple-custom-xaml-c-sharp-button/14087907#14087907

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for, but I'll have to search a bit more as my button has an image as a background, and I want to use another image when it is hovered or pressed.

Comment: While investigating this, I accidently added some local resources. How can I delete them?

Comment: @chuex Can you please help me with this, I can't find a way to add a background image to a visual state of a button. I tried by creating local resources, but I don't know how to implement them into an XAML code of a button.

Comment: I haven't done an image button myself, but found this with just a tiny, tiny bit of research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524508/change-button-image-on-hover-or-click

Comment: I know that, but it's not working.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask a new question. Show what you've done (xaml, code). Link over to the existing samples (Stack Overflow or otherwise) that you have used.  Write down what specifically does not work. "It doesn't work" will probably not get you any answers because it is not specific enough.

Comment: OK, soory :) It worked, it was just misspelling. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chuex Hi, it's been a long time, could you please post an answer so I can reward you.